# How to make a function do something when the enter key is pressed

Tags: javascript

yeah so I searched for ways to do it, but I can't word it well so yeah :(
how can I make entering the enter key fire a function? I'm doing this chat app and of course it's convenient that the enter key is for sending the message, rather than clicking the button. Anyways here's the code I think should work.. 'What should go in the SOMETHING GOES HERE' code?

```
btn.addEventListener('SOMETHING GOES HERE', function(){
  socket.emit('chat', {
    message: message.value,
    handle: handle.value
  });
});
```

sorry if it's been asked before it's just I couldn't find what I was looking for because I can't word it well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to catch keypress event's **you need to listen to either one of these `keyup`, `keydown`, or `keypress`** then identify the desired key by `which`. where the special **code for entering is `13` so you should run your function whenever `e.which == 13`**. But there is a little note here, where **the `btn` itself won't catch `key` events**, so you should bind your event to your `input` instead.

So your code should be something like this:

```js
btn.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {// Replace btn with your input.
  if (e.which == 13) {
    socket.emit('chat', {
      message: message.value,
      handle: handle.value
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: @JuanR4140 Yea, oh my bad, that may not work because `btn` don't get `key` events so you should bind the event to your `input`.